# What happens if you don't split rhubarb?

Tags: roots, rhubarb

I have a friend that has a **rhubarb** plant that was in the same place for at least 13 years, and she wants me to **split** it for her (because she's blind). What am I expecting from such an old plant, because there seems to be no information online about **older plants**?

She's paying me in extra root cuttings from digging up the plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a job to split. The root gets "woody" with age.

You might need an axe or mattock to get the root mass sectioned.

If it's already leafed out (seems likely) you're a bit late for this year, and you'll have to be extra-careful about breaking leaves/stalks. Or wait for next year.

[renewing rhubarb](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/renewing_old_rhubarb_plants)

Comment: I don't split to big pieces, I split it to root segments (2-3 inches), since I'm trying to get a field of plants growing (500+/-) for sales purposes.

Comment: Each piece needs at least one bud (or leaf, if it's too late for those to be buds.)

Comment: I disagree: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFXOga3xy0o